# How to count the number of character in a comma separated line where commas within delimiter are not to be counted as separate?

Tags: linux, string

Let's say I have the following line in my file:

```
HELLO,1410250216446000,1410250216470330,1410250216470367,329,PE,B,T,GALU,[ ,  , T, I],3.38,3,A,A, , , , ,0, ,0,0, ,-Infinity,-Infinity,-Infinity, ,,0
```

if I use

```
grep -a -w HELLO my_file | head -10 | awk -F '[\t,]' '{print NF}' | less
```

output is 32.

But I don't want to count the commas within []. I mean [ ,  , T, I] must be counted as a single word. So that the output of my query is 29.

What will be one line command for doing this in Linux?

Comment: you mean the expected output to be 29 right?

Comment: yes 29 is the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove content inside brackets using `sed`. Then continue counting

```
grep -a -w HELLO my_file|sed "s/\[.*\]//g" | head -10 | awk -F '[\t,]' '{print NF}' | less
```

**output**

```
29
```